# What is the layer on top of my curries?

Tags: spices, curry

Sometimes I see a red film on top of my curry.  It’s like a grainy layer of film.  I don’t think it’s fat because the curry is too hot to solidify by this time.  I’m wondering if it’s powder clogging together? In any case I do think the curry hadbrbb cooked properly.  What is this film?

Comment: How can a film be grainy? Not trying to be picky, just can’t picture it.

Comment: A picture would help as your description seems to contradict itself. To me it just sounds like some fat rising to the surface. I see things like that in some dishes not infrequently. Depends on the fat content of the ingredients.

Comment: Oil floats on water.

Comment: Possibly related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103601/my-curry-is-going-funny-i-dont-know-why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really sounds like a layer of fat/oil floating on top, with some "graininess" from spices or other particles floating in it. The curry being hot is if anything part of why this happens: oil/melted fat floats on water.

As noted in the comments, the description could be clearer, and so it's possible this is incorrect, but that's a very common thing to see on top of curries, and rich stews in general.