# My curry is going funny I don't know why

Tags: curry

First one how it's supposed to look 
Second one is how its looked the last few times I tried to cook it [image][image]

Comment: Welcome! Is this happening at a particular stage of the process (like, it works great until...)? What ingredients are in the curry? Have you made it successfully in the past? If you add more details, we will be better able to help you out :)

Comment: I start with oil and cumin seeds then add my vegetables fry for 2 -3 minutes until slightly soft then I add curry powder, all purpose chicken seasoning they are all powder with fresh crushed garlic fry for another 2 mins then add my water and this is when it starts to go like the 2nd picture I sent in

Comment: Looks like your sauce split - are you sure you aren't adding some milk or cream?

Comment: I do add coconut milk but I added after it started looking like this the milk just made it a lighter colour

Comment: As it does appear your sauce split, you might possibly find your answer in this related/possibly duplicated question [Why are my sauces splitting?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18259/why-are-my-sauces-splitting)

Answer (score 1):

Without the recipe to refer to, I would say that this is due to whatever dairy product you are adding (Butter, cream, yoghurt, coconut milk etc.) splitting due to excessive heat.

If you are using home-made ghee or butter, it could also be due to the milk solids having not been properly separated/removed from the mixture.

The temperature you add dairy, the type of dairy, and the length of time it is exposed to heat are critical factors in not allowing a sauce to split. I would:

1. Reduce the amount of oil/ghee you use in your recipe, and also look into using a high smoke point oil (e.g. rapeseed) instead of ghee or butter. This will eliminate any solid fat coming out of solution when the liquid is added. This type of splitting can also occur when using hybrid spreads (part fat, part oil) for cooking, which is why pure oils (or high quality ghee) is preferred.
2. Add the water/stock etc. and gently simmer rather than boil until the ingredients are cooked to the desired amount.
3. Add the coconut cream etc. towards the end of cooking and do not allow the sauce to come to a boil.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and solutions I really appreciate it.